# How can I build rep when mods insta-delete my posts?

Tags: discussion

Ive been a lurker on the site for years, create an account and my comments are deleted in less than a day of me not being able to respond? OOOKAY

Answer (score 4):

To build rep, your answers must be all of the following: factual, cited by linking to another page or photo (with context for the citation), and/or contain a photo of your own that supports the answer (again, with context). My own belief is that scientific citations are worth far more than citations to a random web page. An example would be your answer to the spots-on-tomato-leaf question. Your answer would not have been deleted if you had included links to information that backed up the assertion in the answer. Uncited anecdotal incidents are best left as comments, not answers.

When I clicked on the question mark icon in the stack's search/menu bar, I found the following, which will explain more fully how to be an excellent resource on this site:

- [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)
- [How do I write a good answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)
- [How to reference material written by others](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Plus, a registered user can always see their recently deleted posts, edit them and flag them to have them undeleted.

Comment: ill just keep lurking and let the mod gods handle it

Comment: @MyDudeCG Hint: the diamond after a user name indicates a moderator (no god though, thank you very much). You were given good advice on how to write a good answer plus how to proceed from there. The ball is in your court now.